# Product Final Price returns 0 instead a real value

Tags: magento2

When `Magento\ProductAlert` checks products for price changing, Product Model unexpected (for me) returns 0.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/e592fca85d1ee26e5c51df056d844a1c09a2d7fc/app/code/Magento/ProductAlert/Model/Observer.php#L235

In line 235, $product->getFinalPrice() must returns calculated product price, but returns 0.

I tried to expand the code to get the price as follows

```
$product = $this->productRepository->getById(
                    $alert->getProductId(),
                    false,
                    $website->getDefaultStore()->getId()
                );

$product->setCustomerGroupId($customer->getGroupId());

$priceModel = $product->getPriceModel();
$productPrice = $priceModel->getFinalPrice(1, $product);
```

But $productPrice still returns as 0.

When i same code into test script - all prices returns with no problem:

/pub/test.php: (Init magento core, ObjectManager, etc. skipped)

```
$productId = '27811'; // test product id

$productRepository = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface::class);

$product = $productRepository->getById(
    $productId,
    false,
    1
);
$priceModel = $product->getPriceModel();

echo $priceModel->getFinalPrice(1,$product); // will output normal price
```

Why zero price returns in first case?
I would appreciate any advice on the topic.